# Change weblogic parameters through a java utility

Tags: weblogic, jmx, mbeans, wlst

I am working on a java utility, deployed with the application on the same server.

Use case: Utility should run through a script file. I should be able to manage weblogic server to change these parameters on active server:

tuning.low parameters:

```
jta-timeout=xx
xa-timeout=xx
inactive-connection-timeout=xx
intial-db-pool=xx
min-db-connection-pool=xx
max-db-connection-pool=xx
db-thread-pool=xx
ui-thread-pool=xx
audit-thread-pool=x
jms-buffer-size=xxx
jms-buffer-count=xxxx

!--Domain Env setup--
oim-xmx=xxxx
oim-xms=xxxx
```

One option is to use WLST embedded. Others are to use rest services provided by weblogic or using JMX. Can you help me to choose. Which would be the preferred way of doing this.

Comment: Most of theses parameters wiil require a server restart to take into account.

Comment: yes, server restart would be there after updating parameters.

Comment: I think WLST is the best way. You will find many code samples on internet to achieve your scripts. JMX will require to create a java client and i'm not sure that all these parameters are settable using WLS REST APIs.